# Are these statistics sufficient?

Tags: self-study, inference, sufficient-statistics

Question (Casella and Berger 6.5):

Let $X_1 \ldots X_n$ be independent random variables with pdfs:

$f(x_i|\theta)= \begin{cases}  \frac{1}{2i\theta}, & -i(\theta - 1)<x_i<i(\theta+1) \\ 0, & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Noting the inequality can be rewritten:

$-\theta<\frac{x_i}{i} - 1<\theta$

Then we can use indicator variables to write the likelihood function in one line:

$L(\theta| D )=\Pi_{i=1}^n f(x_i|\theta)= \left[ \left( \frac{1}{2\theta} \right)^n  \Pi_{i=1}^n I_{[\frac{\min(x_i)}{i} - 1, \infty)}(x_i)I_{(-\infty, \frac{\max(x_i)}{i} -1]}(x_i) \right] \left[ \Pi_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} \right] $

This latter expression being of the form required for the factorisation theorem:

$L(\theta|D)=g(T(D)|\theta)h(D)$

With $h(D)=\Pi_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$ and $g(T(D)|\theta)$ the rest.

The sufficient statistics being $\left( \frac{\min(x_i)}{i} , \frac{\max(x_i)}{i} \right)$

---

I guess I'm wondering if I've missed any requirements to invoke the factorisation theorem. Thoughts appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

$L(\theta| D )=\Pi_{i=1}^n f(x_i|\theta)= \left[ \left( \frac{1}{2\theta} \right)^n \right] \left[ \Pi_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} I_{[\min(\frac{x_i}{i}), \max(\frac{x_i}{i})]}(\frac{x_i}{i}) \right] $

I think this corrects the errors in set up of the indicator variable. Also, I realise it was in the wrong group, it should be part of $h(D)$ and not $g(T(D)|\theta)$ as it involves the individual $x_i$ and not $\theta$.

Comment: I think you've messed up your parentheses; it seems to me it should be $\min(x_i/i)$, not $\min(x_i)/i$.

Comment: It seems to me that you only should need the $\max |x_i|/ i$.

Comment: But how do you know which $i$?

Comment: To expand on my overly-terse comment, assume $\min(x_i) = 1$ and $\max(x_i) = 2$.  Then your sufficient statistics, as written,  are $(1/i, 2/i)$, which can't be right, as $i$ is not defined.

Comment: Your likelihood is wrong, there should be no max nor min when you write it as the product of the $f(x_i|\theta)$. Only one indicator per $i$, $\mathbb{I}_{[-\theta,\theta]}(x_i/i-1)$...

Comment: Jbowman - The parentheses are messed up, the $i$ should be inside, and I'm not sure now that the indicator variables are set up quite right.

Comment: Xi'an - I think there's something in the idea of rolling it into one indicator variable, but I do think we need the statistics in setting up its bounds as otherwise I don't think we couldn't invoke the factorisation theorem.

Comment: Set $Y_i = (x_i/i + 1)/2$ for each $i.$ The $Y_i$ are *iid* uniform on the interval $[\theta,\theta+1],$ which is a familiar exercise setting -- and whose simpler formulation will help you avoid the algebraic errors present in the analysis in the question.